# how to filter selected countries code in IntlPhoneField flutter (need to show countrycode only india and uae when tapping left side of countrycode)

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code to get `intlphonefield`:

```dart
IntlPhoneField(
  showDropdownIcon: false,
  controller: _phoneNumberController,
  initialCountryCode: 'IN',
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
)
```

needs to get filtered countrycode when tapping countrycode, how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the available countries.  You can get the countries from by importing coutries.dart. `import 'package:intl_phone_field/countries.dart';`
Then i filtered them using separate array that i maintained locally. check working code below

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
        var countriess = countries;
      var filteredCountries = ["IN", "AF"];
      List<Country> filter = [];
 void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }
    @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
       countriess.forEach((element) {
         filteredCountries.forEach((filteredc) {
          if (filteredc == element.code){
            filter.add(element);
          }
         });
        });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
        // by the _incrementCounter method above.
        //
        // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
        // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
        // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
            // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
            // change color while the other colors stay the same.
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
            // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
            // in the middle of the parent.
            child: Column(
              // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
              // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
              // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
              //
              // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
              // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
              // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
              // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
              // horizontal).
              //
              // TRY THIS: Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint"
              // action in the IDE, or press "p" in the console), to see the
              // wireframe for each widget.
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                IntlPhoneField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Phone Number',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(),
            ),
        ),
        initialCountryCode: 'IN',
        countries: filter,
        onChanged: (phone) {
            print(phone.completeNumber);
        },
    ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }
```

Or you manually add the country List too.